# What is the analogue of III.4.8 in Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic, for the consequence relation?

Tags: logic, computer-science, model-theory

[p38](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA38) in III.  Semantics of First-Order Languages  of Ebbinghaus' Mathematical Logic says

> Assume two sets of nonlogical symbols: $S' \supset S$.
>
> 4.8.  $\Phi$ is satisfiable with respect to $S$  iff $\Phi$  is satisfiable with respect to $S'$.

[p39](https://books.google.com/books?id=rAy-NliGEPMC&pg=PA39) says

> 4.13 Exercise.  Prove the analogue of 4.8 for  the consequence relation.

4.8  is for satifiability, so is 4.8 already for the consequence relation $\models$?

What is "the analogue of 4.8 for  the consequence relation" in 4.13?

Comment: You can simply apply the Lemma 4.8 considering that $\Phi \vDash \varphi \text {  iff  } \Phi \cup \{ \lnot \varphi \}$ is **not** satisfiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I want to point out that $\Phi$ is assumed to be a set of $S$-sentences in page 38, and I will assume the same throughout this answer. Now, $\Phi$ being satisfiable with respect to $S$ means that there is an $S$-structure which is a model of $\Phi$. On the other hand, the consequence relation refers to the logical entailment of an $S$-sentence $\phi$ with respect to a set of $S$-sentences $\Phi$. So what you are asked to show is:

> Let $S' \supset S$ be sets of non-logical symbols and let $\phi$ be an $S$-sentence. Then $\Phi \models \phi$ with respect to $S$ if and only if $\Phi \models \phi$ with respect to $S'$.

Note that you need to specify  first that $\phi$ is an $S$-sentence (and hence also an $S'$-sentence), since if it was an $S'$-sentence it might not necessarily be an $S$-sentence and hence the statement "$\Phi \models \phi$ with respect to $S'$" might not be well-defined. Further note that the same comment can be made of $\Phi$, which is assumed to be a set of $S$-sentences.